# MySQL :: Run SQL statement within Variable

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I am creating a stored procedure in MySQL 5.1.40 which needs to run a lot of SQL statements.

One particular statement that is often repeated clears a temp table:

```
DELETE FROM w_projection_temp WHERE user_id = uid;
```

The **uid** variable is an IN parameter for the SP.

Is it possible to assign that entire SQL statement to another variable, and then somehow run (evaluate?) that new variable?  eg:

```
DECLARE clear_temp VARCHAR;
SET clear_temp = 'DELETE FROM w_projection_temp WHERE user_id = uid;'
```

MTIA

Comment: why do you want to make this dynamic - you got it right first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PREPARE clear_temp FROM "DELETE FROM w_projection_temp WHERE user_id = ?"
EXECUTE clear_temp USING uid;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE clear_temp;
```